# Is there anyway to export with selected area on map with [Openlayers]?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, openlayers, openlayers-6

AS i am trying to export map with open layers. i am able to export map but by default it exports all the map.

I want to export selected area on the map. is there anyway to do it with Openlayers ?

I'm following this link to export map with Openlayers:

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/export-map.html

Comment: You would need to base it on https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/export-pdf.html where the map is sized as required and the resolution set to fit the output to the required size (note that using he view's `fit` method does not work as expected if the view is rotated).  Or you could try clipping the canvas before calling toBlob/toDataURL